# remove all the white spaces up to the next non-white space starting at nth column using sed

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I am trying to use either sed/awk/etc. on Cygwin to remove all the spaces found on all the lines in a simple text file starting at a specified position and up to the next nonwhite-space character, retaining all the white-spaces before the specified position and after the next nonwhite-space characters.

I've used sed enough to know it's doable, but I haven't been able to figure it out myself or find the right solution. My problem seems simpler than most examples I've found but I've spent enough time that I'm finally willing to admit I need some guidance.

The following before and after will hopefully help explain what I'm trying to do.  In this case, I'd like to perform the operation starting at column "L".

```
BEFORE:    
The quick brown fox     jumped high.
Mary had a little   lamb and ate it
Tom, Dick and Harry   feel   lost.

123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

AFTER:    
The quick brown fox jumped high.
Mary had a little   lamb and ate it
Tom, Dick and Harry feel   lost.
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What must be the output for : `Tom, Brian and Harry   feel   lost.`

Comment: Why tag it with awk if you want a sed solution? Why say in the subject you want a sed solution if you're happy with other solutions? Edit your question subject and/or tags to clarify what you really want.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using regular expression implementing the range quantifier `{ n }` in sed.

```
#!/bin/sh
STRING=$(cat <<EOF
The quick brown fox     jumped high.
Mary had a little   lamb and ate it
Tom, Dick and Harry   feel   lost.
EOF
)
echo "$STRING" | sed -r 's/^(.{20}) */\1/g'
```

Output

```
The quick brown fox jumped high.
Mary had a little   lamb and ate it
Tom, Dick and Harry feel   lost.
```

Comment: +1 nice, it's unusual to get a good sed solution that involves counting!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to remove extraneous spaces starting with column "L" (column 20).  Assuming that your input is in a file called `before`, run:

```
$ awk -v c=20 '{x=substr($0,c); gsub(/  */, " ", x); print substr($0,1,c-1) x}' before
The quick brown fox can't jump
Mary had a little   lamb and ate it
Tom, Dick and Harry feel lost.
```

Taking the `awk` commands one at a time:

- `-v c=20`

  This creates a variable `c` with the starting column information.
- `x=substr($0,c)`

  This creates a variable `x` with the text from the part of the line that we want to alter.
- `gsub(/  */, " ", x)`

  This replaces multiple spaces with a single space where ever they occur in the variable `x`.
- `print substr($0,1,c-1) x}`

  This prints out the start of the line unchanged followed by our variable `x` which has the extraneous spaces removed.

#### Alternative interpretation

Suppose that we only want to remove spaces that start at column "L" while leaving extraneous spaces that follows words after that point:

```
$ awk -v c=20 '{x=substr($0,c); sub(/^  */, " ", x); print substr($0,1,c-1) x}' before
The quick brown fox can't jump
Mary had a little   lamb and ate it
Tom, Dick and Harry feel   lost.
```

The visible difference between this and the previous version is that this leaves the extraneous spaces between "feel" and "lost" in the last line.

Comment: awk fields, arrays and strings all start at index 1, not 0. `substr($0,0,...)` is only "working" because `0` is an invalid index and so awk defaults to using `1`. You'd get the same result with `substr($0,-357,...)`.

Answer (score 1):

If the original text is saved in data.txt:

```
sed -e 's/^\(.\{19\}\)[[:space:]]\+/\1 /' data.txt
```

Starting at beginning, count 19 characters and make it a group (`\(.\{19\}\)` for back reference (`\1`). Then match one or more spaces - `[[:space:]]\+`. Replace the whole match with the back reference and a single whitespace.

Comment: +1 nice, it's unusual to get a good sed solution that involves counting!

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk -v p=21 '{print substr($0,1,p-1) gensub(/^\s+/,"","",substr($0,p))}' file
The quick brown fox jumped high.
Mary had a little   lamb and ate it
Tom, Dick and Harry feel   lost.
```